# SQLServer update statement chokes on null value, even with isNull()

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

Please note that I've changed the names of the tables and fields to make this short and understandable.

I have a query that, boiled down, comes to this:

```
update destTable 
set destField = ( select top 1 isnull(s.sourceField, '') from sourceTable s 
where <various matches between the destTable table and the s table>
);
```

(I'm aware of the syntax 'update destTable set destField ... from destTable d, sourceTable s ...' but am not sure how to put the "top 1" into it.)

From this I get the SQLServer 2012 Express result:

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'destField', table 'destTable'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

For both tables all of the fields are defined as not-null and default ('').

The "top 1" is important because the sourceTable might have multiple matches for the "where" clauses.

I queried all the rows of sourceTable and found that all of its sourceField values are non-null.  Yet I get the result.

The nature of the query is that out of maybe 1000 destTable records the match with sourceTable will yield a match for only 300 rows.  The other 700 destTable records won't have a match.

I'm not understanding what SQLServer is doing to me.  This query works just fine when I last ran it with MySQL.

Thanks in advance,
Jerome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the query is not returning any rows . . . hence producing a NULL value.  Move the `isNULL()` outside the subquery:

```
update destTable 
set destField =  isnull((select top 1 s.sourceField
                         from sourceTable s 
                         where <various matches between the destTable table and the s table>
                        ), '');
```

By the way, normally I would advocate `coalesce()` in this situation, because it is the standard.  However, the two behave differently, as described by Aaron Bertrand [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/).  In particular, the first argument appears to be evaluated twice, which is quite expensive when it is a subquery.  `Isnull()`, apparently, does not have this problem.

Comment: Putting isNull() where you told me got my problem solved.  Thanks very much.